# spring @RequestMapping URI template error

Tags: spring, uri, spring-annotations

I have a question about the @RequestMapping URI template. I built a controller to handle user details update. And I write two methods below.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateUser/{applicationModuleType}/{userCountryCode}/{applicationModuleId}")
public @ResponseBody Object handleUpdateUserDetailsRequest(@PathVariable String applicationModuleType,
                                                           @PathVariable String userCountryCode, 
                                                           @PathVariable String applicationModuleId,
                                                           Model model) {
    System.out.println("************ form:Submited");
    }
    return null;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/updateUser/**")
public @ResponseBody Object handleRequest(Model model) {
    System.out.println("************ form:Submited all");
    return null;
}
```

And the request URI is like /project_name/updateUser/app/au/132

And when I ran this app in tomcat, the first method is never called. The controller is always use the second one. But in spring framework doc, it said "A method can have any number of @PathVariable annotations".

So, I cannot figure out why I cannot have three @PathVariable annotations in a method.

Another thing is, if I change the first method @RequestMapping annotation like below, it can be called.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/updateUser/app/{userCountryCode}/{applicationModuleId}")
public @ResponseBody Object handleUpdateUserDetailsRequest(@PathVariable String userCountryCode, 
                                                           @PathVariable String applicationModuleId,
                                                           Model model) {
    System.out.println("************ form:Submited");
    }
    return null;
}
```

It seems that spring cannot handle three @PathVariable annotations in ONE method.

Is there anyone who can tell me why or where I did wrong, please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Nothing to do with path variables, you simply have conflicting mappings.

```
/updateUser/**
```

and

```
/updateUser/{applicationModuleType}/{userCountryCode}/{applicationModuleId}
```

will match the same URI:s.

Answer (score 2):

When three @PathVariable annotations Spring will think @RequestMapping(value="/updateUser/**")
match more than that /updateUser/{applicationModuleType}/{userCountryCode}/{applicationModuleId}

If you remove

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateUser/**")
```

you will found it would invoke

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateUser/{applicationModuleType}/{userCountryCode}/{applicationModuleId}")
```

You should using @RequestParam to pass parameters. not @PathVariable.